# JMeter Asynchronous Delay In Specific HTTP Requests

Tags: asynchronous, jmeter, stress-testing

Given an API with two endpoints:

1. `submit`
2. `result`

And given that it takes 20 `submits` to be made after which the API server starts to calculate the result for a specific user

And given that such a calculation takes between 1 to 5 seconds to complete

And given that currently my `JMeter` script successfully is able to make all those submissions and that it incessantly queries the `result endpoint` until it receives the result

And given that the annoying matter facing me currently is that on account of the `result endpoint` being a very light/quick request (in the case the result is not calculated as of yet), that more requests end up going to the `result endpoint` as opposed to the submit endpoint.

And given that such behaviour distorts the measurement of the overall throughput.

And given that adding a `Constant Timer` blocks the entire request thread and no other requests get made until the timer has completed

**Then my question is:** Does `JMeter` provide in one way or the other the ability to either:

1. prioritize requests(so `results endpoint` would have a lower priority) or either to
2. introduce a delay to a HTTP request on an asynchronous basis so that the `result endpoint` request does not end up hogging all the attention of my API?

Comment: Could you please show a snapshot of your plan here? That's going to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And given that adding a Constant Timer blocks the entire request
>   thread and no other requests get made until the timer has completed

Looks like you having your samples in the same thread group, aren't you?

If yes, divide it then: establish a separate thread group for your "result" requests, and set the timings you want there.

Although it would be great if you show your plan first.

**UPD**: So you need to communicate between threads, as it appears.

Then you may use JMeter properties (which seem to be the simplest and roughest way). 
Or use files or other storage (some simple in-mem DB, for example) as shared resourse.
Or use this: https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/.
Or write the stuff combining any of these approaches yourself.

Comment: @yuri_g You are correct that I only utilize one Thread Group for all my endpoints. My result endpoint needs some specific id provided by the response received from the submission endpoint. I will just need to figure out a way to pass such value from one thread group to another.